docker wsl build arm and x86 in the same time
I can build docker image for DockerHUB on WSL with Intel x64 using command:
docker build --tag sosnus15/pinger

and I can build on the same machine for arm based computers using command:
docker build --platform arm64 --tag sosnus15/pinger

But how to build on both platform in same time? I try:
docker build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 --tag sosnus15/pinger:1.0.3 .

console output is:
Error response from daemon: "amd64,linux" is an invalid component of "linux/amd64,linux/arm64": platform specifier component must match "^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$": invalid argument

So... How I can do 2 images on 2 platform in the same time using one command docker build?

I don't think that's possible; I think docker build only builds one image at a time.  (Does your ARM image work on ARM-based hosts, if you're building it on an x86-based system?)

For multi-platform images, you should use buildx:
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 --tag sosnus15/pinger:1.0.3 --push .

Note that this also requires pushing to a registry since the local image store, at least before the containerd transition comes out of experimental, only supports a single platform image.
And if you have not already done so, you'll need to setup a builder. More details on that are available from Docker's docs: https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/
